# Raspberry Pi installing discord.py on specific python version

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord.py

I am trying to run my discord bot on my raspberry pi.

I have installed python version 3.11.5 on my raspberry pi which is the version I need to run my code.

When I try to run the "python3.11 main.py" it results in "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'" on the import discord line.

However, when I run python3 (which is Python 3.5.3for me) and then "import discord" and print(discord.**version**) it prints 1.7.3.

I have tried many times to install discord.py using pip but everytime it gives me the same error and is not installing on python version 3.11.5

My question boils down to how do I use pip to install discord on a specific python version. In this case python 3.11.5 and make python 3.11.5 my default under python3

Comment: I am running on Raspbian

Edit: Didnt understand question

Comment: Running "python3.11 -m pip install discord.py" gives me the error "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/:  There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Comment: U could try like: `py -m pip install discord` and run the script with `py main.py`

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to run my bot with python 3.11 either. Not sure what incompatibility is going on with this new release. You'll be able to run it with 3.10.7 (latest successfully tested for me)